# Advantages of arrays of structures over parallel arrays in 6502 assembly language?

Tags: assembly, 6502

My understanding from writing a lot of 6502 back in the day is that parallel arrays are better than structures for storing data.

Imagine you want to have a table of monster stats that in C would be defined something like this

```c
struct Monster {
  unsigned char hitPoints;
  unsigned char damage;
  unsigned char shieldLevel;
  char* name;
};
```

You could store it as an array of structures

```c
static Monster s_monsters[] = {
  { 5,   1, 0, "orc", },
  { 50, 10, 5, "dragon", },
  { 10,  3, 1, "goblin", },
};
```

Or you could store it as parallel arrays (usually using macros or tools to generate). Note: I'm showing the code in C but please imagine it's 6502 assembly.

```c
unsigned char Monster_hitPoints[] = { 5, 50, 10, };
unsigned char Monster_damage[] = { 1, 10, 3, },
unsigned char Monster_sheildLevel[] = { 0, 5, 1, };
unsigned char Monster_nameLow[] = { 
   &m_orc_name & 0xFF, 
   &m_dragon_name & 0xFF,
   &m_goblin_name & 0xFF, 
};
unsigned char Monster_nameHigh[] = { 
   &m_orc_name >> 8 , 
   &m_dragon_name >> 8,
   &m_goblin_name >> 8, 
};
```

In 6502, given an itemNdx you can access all the fields with parallel arrays like this

```
ldx itemNdx
lda Monster_hitPoints,x   ; access hitpoints
...
lda Monster_damage,x      ; access damage
...
lda Monster_shieldLevel,x ; access shieldLevel
...
lda Monster_nameLow,x     ; access name
sta pageZeroStringPointer
lda Monster_nameHigh,x
sta pageZeroStringPointer + 1
ldy #0
lda (pageZeroStringPointer),y
```

Where as if you use a struct instead of parallel arrays it becomes

```
lda itemNdx
clc          ; have to compute offset
asl a        ; a = itemNdx * 2   
asl a        ; a = itemNdx * 4
adc itemNdx  ; a = itemNdx * 5
tax          ; x = itemNdx * 5 

lda s_monsters+Monster.hitPoints,x   ; access hitpoints
...
lda s_monsters+Monster.damage,x      ; access damage
...
lda s_monsters+Monster.shieldLevel,x ; access shieldLevel
...
lda s_monsters+Monster.name,x        ; access name
sta pageZeroStringPointer
lda s_monsters+Monster.name+1,x
sta pageZeroStringPointer + 1
ldy #0
lda (pageZeroStringPointer),y        ; a is now first char of name
```

The structure version has to compute the offset to each structure. In the case above that's 5 more instructions vs the parallel array version. On top of which the math for computing the offset is hand coded, meaning it has to be re-written anytime the size if a structure changes. On top of that you can only have a table of `256 / sizeof(Monster)` large. If you have more fields (20 to 30 is not uncommon), that would mean your tables could only have 8 to 12 entries where as with parallel arrays you can have 256 entries. One more advantage if if you want to iterate over the table. With parallel arrays you just increment x `inx`, one instruction. With structures you'd have to add sizeof(monster) which add only works with a would be

```
 txa
 clc
 adc #sizeof(Monster)
 tax
```

That's 3 more instructions than the parallel arrays version.

That seems like parallel arrays are an objective win for 6502 assembly language but there's this obscure comment by John Carmack from [his plan file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ESWAT/john-carmack-plan-archive/master/by_day/johnc_plan_19980204.txt)

> ... actually, all the way back to understanding the virtues of structures over parallel arrays in apple II assembly language.. ...

Does anyone know what those advantages are?

The only advantages I can think of off the top of my head is that it's easier to allocate a dynamic array with arrays of structs but most games didn't allocate anything back in 6502 days. They hardcoded fixes sized arrays of memory so that doesn't seem like that can be it. 6502 didn't have a cache either so there's no cache advantage.

Also you can address more than 256 items if you go full on pointers but full on pointers are **much** slower and require **much** more code than either of the methods shown above therefore they are usually options of last resort.

```
; setup pointer
lda itemNdx
ldx #sizeof(Monster)
jsr multiplyAX       ; 8->16 bit multiply is around 70 cycles result in A(low), X(high)
clc
adc #s_monster && 0xFF
sta POINTER
txa
adc #s_monster >> 8
sta POINTER + 1

ldy #Monster.hitPoints   ; access hitpoints
lda (POINTER),y   
...
ldy #Monster.damage      ; access damage
lda (POINTER),y 
...
ldy #Monster.shieldLevel ; access shieldLevel
lda (POINTER),y 
...
ldy #Monster.name       ; access name
lda (POINTER),y
sta pageZeroStringPointer
ldy #Monster.name+1    
lda (POINTER),y
sta pageZeroStringPointer + 1
ldy #0
lda (pageZeroStringPointer),y        ; a is now first char of name
```

You could get rid of the multiply by making a parallel array of pointers to each item. You'd still have 2 lines of setup that are not needed for parallel arrays and you'd still be making the rest of the code slower and larger. 8 cycles per access vs 5 and 5 bytes per access vs 3.

Basically you would only use pointers if you absolutely have to. If you can choose parallel arrays then it seems like you should always choose them.

Comment: The problem is that X and Y registers are 8-bit and cannot be used as index of structure element.

Comment: This Q sounds to me way too generic. There are more options how to hard-code certain tricks into it, if your task allows that, I'm unfortunately not familiar with 6502, and Z80+x86 differs too much, but sometimes we did interleave structures in memory, so each element was at +256 address (moving pointers by incrementing just upper 8 bits of ptr), or the elements had fixed size and the pointer was incremented partially during processing to get over each field, and end pointing at start of next element, or fixing size of element to power of two, so multiply was shift only, etc...

Comment: When I last implemented a raster IRQ table for the C64, I used an array of structured data for the next rasterline to setup the IRQ for and the ISR payload to jump to. This was simpler and didn't have any disadvantages because the data was only ever used in a linear order. That said, I can't think of a **general** advantage of structured data. It really depends on the usecase.

Answer (score 2):

Parallel arrays work really fast within a fixed set of parameters using absolute addressing. However, the moment you get beyond that and have to use zero page indexing, the tables are turned.

```
;  Assuming MONSTER_PTR is zp, set to the start of the current structure
ldy  #Monster.hitPoints
lda  (MONSTER_PTR),y
...
ldy  #Monster.damage
lda  (MONSTER_PTR),y
```

With parallel arrays that exceeded a single page limit, a pointer would have to be reset for each array. In addition, once pointers are in play, long index calculations can be replaced with simple moves of pre-calculated pointers or single shifts to index pointer tables.

Given the advantages (at least in the terms of flexibility he was using), the ability to dynamically allocate items comes as a freebie. He was not clear in his writing but this appears to be what he's getting at.

Comment: that's still a net loss. Setting up `MONSTER_PTR` is several instructions so worse. `lda (xxx),y` is slower than `lda xxx,y` so that's worse. And, having to set `ldy #offset` for each field is slower than not having to load the offset at all so that's worse so I'm not understanding the advantage here. Plus, on a 6502 with only 64k of memory, the times when you need more than 256 structures in a table are few and far between. Sure if you really need that then you just have to do it the above way but that's not really an advantage rather it's a necessity.

Comment: The advantages of parallel arrays were the first thing I mentioned, as was the fact that direct mode is always more flexible than indexed (since there is no equivalent of (ptr+offset),idx in 6502. However, the moment you start having to use pointers then this advantage is lost and structures become more efficient for the reasons given. Think about what you would have to do to use pointers on parallel arrays - that, I think, is what he was getting at.

Comment: Sure ok, but when we're discussing advantages vs disavantages the discussion should arguably be "use the most efficient method until you can't" which basically means "prefer parallel arrays until you can't use them". Otherwise if the advice is "use pointers and array of structures over parallel arrays" then 19 out of 20 times you be writing more code and less efficient code.

Comment: That, I agree with wholeheartedly.

Answer (score 1):

the only point, where parallel arrays are better than structure access (which brings the need of calculating the current monster's Address on every access) you be, if you have ready-set-up pointers to each array in the zero page:

```
; set up zero page, done only once per level
; (per level, per stage, per dungeon, whatever)

lda #<monster_HP_list_for_this_level
sta $f0
lda #>monster_HP_list_for_this_level
sta $f1

lda #<monster_damage_list_for_this_level
sta $f2
lda #>monster_damage_list_for_this_level
sta $f3

lda #<monster_shield_list_for_this_level
sta $f4
lda #>monster_shield_list_for_this_level
sta $f5

...

; here you'd have instant access to the monster's values :
lda ($F0),y   ; monster Nr. y's HP
; or 
lda ($F4),y   ; monster Nr. y's Shield level
```

BUT:
you may only have 256 monsters ( and a lot of free zeropage adresses, this shouldn't be so much of a problem)

on every new situation (e.g. you reach a new map, enter a new dungeon etc.) the zero-page pointers could be updated, to point to the new level's monsters

Comment: how is `lda (zeropagedamgelist),y` better than `load nonzeropagedamagelist,x`? the later is 5 cycles, the former 6, the later requires no setup, the former does. I think I don't understand your answer. Maybe you're assuming data is loaded at runtime into arbitrary locations? But that's not how people programmed most 6502 apps.

Comment: you could load the zeropage pointer new, for each "level" you reach, each new dungeon you enter etc. but that's a good point, I will change my answer accordingly